# GD function not working

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to create a thumbnail images for my website. I extract the files using

```
   $chapterZip = new ZipArchive();
if ($chapterZip->open($_FILES['chapterUpload']['tmp_name'])) 
    {
        if($chapterZip->extractTo("Manga/".$_POST['mangaName']."/".$_POST['chapterName']))
        {
         for($i = 0; $i < $chapterZip->numFiles; $i++) {
```

and then loop through the images and with the first image I send the path to a this method

```
 function createthumb($source,$output,$new_w,$new_h)
```

all the values are read in fine up until I try to use the following code

```
if (preg_match("/jpg|jpeg/",$ext)){$src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($source);}
    if (preg_match("/png/",$ext)){$src_img=imagecreatefrompng($source);}
    if (preg_match("/gif/",$ext)){$src_img=imagecreatefromgif($source);}
```

the prerequisite for the regular expression is being met by the file and the code is being ran, yet the imagecreate function doesn't create the new file, I checked my phpinfo file to see if the GD library is enable and it is, so in short I don't have a clue whats wrong.

http://www.neuromanga.com/phpinfo.php

Comment: Creating a new ZipArchive object doesn't extract anything... are you sure the extracted files exist at $source?

Comment: The images are being extracted fine I'm trying to keep the code brief

Comment: If you've already extracted the files, you should use [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) to determine the file type

Comment: Your preg_match calls will fail you if you end up with a filename like 'thisisnotajpg.bmp'. The 'jpg' portion will match, but the imagecreatefromjpg() will barf because the file's really a .bmp. You should put a `$` at the end of the pattern at least, or use something like FileInfo or getimagesize() to unambiguously determine image type. Going by filename extension is unreliable.

Comment: Fine I will do this, but the issue is the the imagecreatefrom function as even when the function is called the image still isn't being created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure GD is properly installed and the function exists:

```
<pre>
<?
$arr = get_defined_functions();
sort($arr['internal']);
print_r($arr);
?>
```

also. Although this "creates" the image, you still have to write it to either the screen or a file to be able to use it. at the state it's in using imagecreatefrom[..whatever] it's just a object in your current state in your web app and has not been rendered out for storage or display. for that you need to do whatever you're going to do and use [imagejpeg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)
 or [imagegif](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php) or [imagepng](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) to actually render the object back out to some destination.  you can test this by executing `echo $src_img` which should print something like: `Resource id #1`

Comment: the regular expression in the code is being read in fine its the fact that the imagecreate functions aren't being run, as I checked to see if $src_img exists and it didnt

Comment: Thanks for that, figured out quite a bit using that method

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your path to $source is correct. What is $src_img if it's not a new image?

Comment: the source image is being read in fine, but the $src_img assigned in those lines of code... before that it didn't exist